# Swiper addSlide HTML bug

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

**Function addSlide**
addSlide function does not work properly because it adds plain text to the HTML instead of adding an HTML object. Has anyone found a solution to this problem that would allow the image to be inserted somewhere other than at the beginning or end of slider?

At first I thought it was an error in my template, but I made a clean instance of swiper and the result is exactly the same as the error.

```html
<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper">
  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    ...
  </div>
  <!-- If we need pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

  <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

  <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
  <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
```

```js
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  speed: 400,
  spaceBetween: 100,
});

const slider = document.querySelector('.swiper').swiper;

slider.addSlide(1, '<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10"</div>')
```

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/5vLocsjb/

Comment: Fwiw: This only seems to happen when you try to add a slide in between existing slides (indices) and not for a new index e.g. 10 - [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/31j7zuct/)

Comment: @DarkBee it's mean that i can't add slide between two existing?

Comment: If I were you I'd open a ticket on the github page. The code shown should be correct according to their [documentation](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#method-swiper-addSlide)

Comment: Oh... I'd open a ticket when author back from vacation.